# thank you page does it is not displayed woocommerce

Tags: orders

after the checkout the standard thank you page is tnot displayed:
https://www.mrgusto.de/zahlung/order-received/7199/?key=wc_order_Vu30eTRfdbz7z
We get hte 404 page

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

I have checked the settings it seems all fine, Elementor is updated.

The page is quite important so we need some hints on how to solve it.

Comment: Can you go to **woocommerce** > **settings** > **advanced** and check your end point for **"order received"**. This is usually something like "order-received". If you see something else written there, it might be due to a string translation plugin like [WPML String translation](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/thank-you-page-404-not-found/).